# how to use IPN to check the Cancel subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

i have created a paypal form for monthly subscription. 
I've set notify_url in it. Its works fine. When someone subscribe to my site. It does come to my notify page and then i store transaction details in my database. Now my problem is when some of my subscriber press "Cancel Subscription" from his paypal account. I need to update my database with "Cancel" status. How i can do this with IPN?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. It tells you. It sends you a subscr_cancel transaction.

Comment: I am not getting what you wany to say? can you please elaborate?

Comment: What part of 'it sends you a subscr_cancel transaction' don't you understand?